# How to design services to fetch data that are required to be called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

I have a `service` that returns a `promise`.

```
function GetSuggestedPeersService($http, SITE_CONFIG) {
        var getSuggestedPeersService = this;

        var data;

        getSuggestedPeersService.getSuggestedPeersList = function() {
            var baseUrl = SITE_CONFIG.baseUrl + "fetchSuggestedPeers";
            var response = $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : baseUrl,
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data : data
            });
            return response;
        }

        getSuggestedPeersService.setSuggestedPeers = function(suggestedPeers) {
            getSuggestedPeersService.suggestedPeers = suggestedPeers;
        }

        getSuggestedPeersService.getSuggestedPeers = function() {
            return getSuggestedPeersService.suggestedPeers;
        }

    }
```

Now I use the following in the Controller to resolve the promise:

```
//gets the suggested peers
var promiseSuggestedPeers = GetSuggestedPeersService.getSuggestedPeersList();
promiseSuggestedPeers.then(function (response) {
    peerHealthController.GetSuggPeersShow = response.data;
    GetSuggestedPeersService.setSuggestedPeers(peerHealthController.GetSuggPeersShow);

    return peerHealthController.GetSuggPeersShow;
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Something went terribly wrong Suggested Peers.");
});
```

Now my question is call this service multiple times and need to update this on other service calls as well.

What is the best way to write the controller part so as not to repeat the resolve promise every time I call the service?

Comment: You must be a Java programmer. Only a Java programmer would use a noun like "suggestedPeers" more times than the number of lines in the code.

Comment: @georgeawg Lol. Yeah, you got it right. You seem to be an experienced angular programmer.  Do you have any suggestions for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been long time.

But I just wanted to answer this question.

The best way to design this would be to use a factory. So this will become a reusable service.

An example code can be the following:

```
var httpMethods = peerHealthApp.factory('HttpService',HttpService);

httpMethods.$inject = ['$http', 'SITE_CONFIG'];

function HttpService($http, SITE_CONFIG){
    console.log("SITE_CONFIG from Peer Service: " + SITE_CONFIG);
    var factory = {
            httpGet : function(relativePath,data){
                var baseUrl = SITE_CONFIG.baseUrl + relativePath;
                var response = $http({
                    method : 'GET',
                    url : baseUrl,
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    data : data
                });
                return response;

            },
            httpPost : function(relativePath, data){
                var baseUrl = SITE_CONFIG.baseUrl + relativePath;
                var response = $http({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : baseUrl,
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    data : data
                });
                return response;
            }

    };


    return factory;

}
```

And the above can be used again and again like the following:

```
var data=$.param({
    "url":moderatedArticleLink
 });
var promiseURLMetaData = HttpService.httpPost("parseUrlMetadata", data);
promiseURLMetaData.then(function (response) {
    var urlMetaData = response.data;
    return urlMetaData;
    })
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Something went terribly wrong while trying to get URL Meta Data.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to write the controller part so as not to repeat the resolve promise every time I call the service?

Instead of saving the data in a service, I recommend saving the promise:

```
if ( !Service.get() ) {
    var promise = Service.fetch();
    Service.set(promise);
});

Service.get().then(function (response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
}).catch( function(errorResponse) {
    console.log(errorResponse.status);
    throw errorResponse;
});
```

By checking for the promise and only fetching if necessary, multiple controllers can share the data without caring about the order of controller instantiation. This avoids race conditions and multiple XHRs to the same resource.